# Clean way to test many conditions of different values?

Tags: javascript

So , I want to test many conditions, for different values... right now is just a bunch of if,else statements...

But it looks ugly im sure there must be a better way...

any ideas ?

Im thinking maybe with loops but or putting all  vars in an array, but I cant figure out how..

Thx!

```
var dataObject = {}

if (newState.playerId){
  dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = newState.playerId
}else{
  dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = this.state.playerId
}

if (newState.pageLimit){
  dataObject ["page[limit]"] = newState.pageLimit
}else{
  dataObject["page[limit]"] = this.state.pageLimit
}

if (newState.timeFrom){
  dataObject["time[from]"] = newState.timeFrom
}else{
  dataObject["time[from]"] = this.state.timeFrom
}

if (newState.timeTo){
  dataObject["time[to]"] = newState.timeTo
}else{
  dataObject["time[to]"] = this.state.timeTo
}

if (newState.gameId){
  dataObject["filter[game_id]"] = newState.gameId
}else{
  dataObject["filter[game_id]"] = this.state.gameId
}

if (newState.customerId){
  dataObject["filter[customer_id]"] = newState.customerId
}else{
  dataObject["filter[customer_id]"] = this.state.customerId
}

if (newState.currency){
  dataObject["filter[currency]"] = newState.currency
}else{
  dataObject["filter[currency]"] = this.state.currency
}

if (newState.variant){
  dataObject["filter[locale]"] = newState.locale
}else{
  dataObject["filter[locale]"] = this.state.locale
}

if (newState.variant){
  dataObject["filter[demo]"] = newState.demo
}else{
  dataObject["filter[demo]"] = this.state.demo
}
```

Comment: Use a loop over properties! Can you show us the defintions of `newState` and `this.state`?

Comment: Are the last two blocks of if-else based on `newState.variant`? Or `locale` and `demo` state respectively?

Comment: @GiorgioMartini have you solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reducing your condition

First, you can use javascript's `||` operator and change:

```
if (newState.playerId){
  dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = newState.playerId
}else{
  dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = this.state.playerId
}
```

To the much reduced:

```
dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = newState.playerId || this.state.playerId;
```

## DRY up your code

You can use an array of properties:

```
var propertyList = ["playerId", "pageLimit", "timeFrom" /* etc. */]
```

Because object properties can be referenced using square brackets you can  loop through them like this:

```
propertyList.forEach(function(property){
    dataObject[property] = newState[property] || this.state[property]
});
```

**Disclaimer:** This solution is not taking into account your embedded objects (like "filter") and the slight variations in your naming schemes (like "player_id" vs "playerId").

Three solutions occur to me:

1. **Use consistent naming conventions**
   In other words in the `dataObject` that you build have the same naming pattern as your `state` object.
2. Use a **helper function**
   Convert the names in your for loop using some kind of consistent pattern that changes `playerId` to `player_id` when those kinds of changes need to be done. (this will still not work if you plan to use "filter", "time" or "page".
3. **Use objects/arrays (as in @ssube's solution)**
   You could also use an array or an object to translate your property names between objects. I won't give you an example - @ssube has done so already.

Comment: Not all of the destination fields are filters, unfortunately. I can't find a consistent naming convention on `dataObject`, so I think you need both names for each property.

Comment: True hadn't realised they were all fitlers, I realised there were slight differences in the names anyway though. It makes more sense to use consistent naming convention though (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

Use the or (`||`) operator taking benefit of the [short circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation), e.g.

```
 dataObject["filter[player_id]"] = newState.playerId ||  this.state.playerId
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a recurring pattern here:

```
if (newState[srcField]) {
  dataObject[destField] = newState[srcField]
} else {
  dataObject[destField] = this.state[srcField]
}
```

Thanks to JS' handling of the OR operator, you can simplify that to:

```
dataObject[destField] = newState[srcField] || this.state[srcField];
```

Since you have the field names, you can set up a loop like:

```
var dataObject = {};
var fields = [
  ['playerId', 'filter[player_id]'],
  ['pageLimit', 'page[limit]']
];

fields.forEach(function (field) {
  var src = field[0], dest = field[1];
  dataObject[dest] = newState[src] || this.state[src];
});
```

and voila, the fields will be copied across with appropriate renaming.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataObject = {};
dataObject['filter[player_id]'] = newState.playerId || this.state.playerId;
dataObject['filter[game_id]'] = newState.gameId || this.state.gameId;
dataObject['filter[customer_id]'] = newState.customerId || this.state.customerId;
dataObject['filter[currency]'] = newState.currency || this.state.currency;
dataObject['filter[locale]'] = newState.variant ? newState.locale : this.state.locale;
dataObject['filter[demo]'] = newState.variant ? newState.demo: this.state.demo;
dataObject['page[limit]'] = newState.pageLimit || this.state.pageLimit;
dataObject['time[from]'] = newState.timeFrom || this.state.timeFrom;
dataObject['time[to]'] = newState.timeTo || this.state.timeTo;
```